# Узнать сколько совпадений в запросе LEFT

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте!
Помогите, пжлст, составить запрос, если таковой вообще возможен.
Есть две таблицы. в одной id уникальные

1. 1 2 3 4

В другой, id - > встречаются

1. 1 2 2 2

Запрос не главный, а через JOIN:
join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__addfavor', 'cf') . ' ON cn.id = cf.fav_item ' )

Возможно ли в нем, добиться того, чтобы при запросе у нас оказалось значение совпадений, в случае примера = 1, 3, 0, 0

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select(
        array(
            $db->quoteName('m.core_content_id'),
            $db->quoteName('m.content_item_id'),
            $db->quoteName('cn.hits'),
            $db->quoteName('cf.fav_item')
            )
    );

    $query->from($db->quoteName('#__contentitem_tag_map', 'm'));

        ->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__content', 'cn') . ' ON m.content_item_id = cn.id')
        ->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__addfavor', 'cf') . ' ON cn.id = cf.fav_item ' );
```

==============================

изрядно сокращен - оч много selecta, INNER и LEFT / что вам от этого станет яснее - теперь мне не понятно ))))

Comment: Вообще ничего не понятно. И также не понятно, почему было создано именно 2 таблицы, для связи между числами? Когда можно было и одной обойтись. Видимо вы делаете, что - то типо вложений? Пожалуйста добавьте в вопрос код и больше информации.

Comment: Таблиц гораздо больше чем две. Я не знаю как еще обьяснить( Связано это с особенностями архитектуры. В одной находятся id пользователей. В другой, заказы (тоже присутсвуют такие же id, но в отличие от первой - не уникальны и повторяются в столбце). Вот и нужно узнать (конечно желательно через один уже существующий запрос) - сколько раз пользователь совершал заказ. Т.е. количество повторений ID во второй таблице на это и укажет.

Comment: Раз система есть, пожалуйста, добавьте полный код, где работаете с запросом и что пытаетесь сделать. Не видно как вы работаете с `sql`, какие-то куски непонятные добавили и хотите, чтобы кто-то с ходу понял, что вы там делаете. Какие таблицы, что где находится, на ходу что-ли придумывать самим вида `tableName`?

Comment: Не думаю, если я выложу пол страницы текста запросов к разным таблицам - станет из непонятно, сразу все понятно. Пример я написал = какая разница как таблица называется, если решение есть и его знают, то его сразу напишут.

Comment: @Дмитрий минимизируйте данные и запрос и выложите минимально рабочий пример. Но похоже, что Вам нужен какой-нибудь `SUM(CASE WHEN xxx is NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)`, где `xxx` - ключ из таблицы, цепляемой по `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

```
select T1.id, count(T2.id) qty from
T1 left join T2 on T1.id=T2.id
group by T1.id
```